# Angularjs ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hi I have two fields

```
<input 
    type="text"                 
    ng-model="postFlightData.schedule_date" 
    ng-change="getFlightNo()"
>
```

this will populate the select option here

```
<select 
    ng-model="postFlightData.flight_number_id" 
    data-placeholder = "Select Flight No."
    ng-disabled="!postFlightData.schedule_date"
    options="flight_nos"
    ng-options="flight_no as flight_no.name for flight_no in flight_nos"
    ng-change="getPsi()"
>
</select>
```

this again call function getPsi() working fine at first attempt but my problem is when trying to change first field value after selecting both at first attempt it should only call getFlightNo() but it will again call getPsi() function and give type error null error any idea on how to solve this problem please do i have to paste my angular controller please help

Comment: What do you mean by: `when trying to change first field value after selecting both` ?

Comment: lets say i choose schedule_date it will call getFlightNo() and then i choose flight_number_id it will call  getPsi() and give result as expected and the both field retained the old values. and now if i choose schedule_date again it should only call getFlightNo() but it is calling getPsi() aswell

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you change `ng-change="getPsi()"` to `ng-click="getPsi()"`?
If not, I assume that second time when you choose `schedule_time`, the option is selected automatically right?

Comment: yes the the option is automatically selected ng-click not calling getPsi()

Comment: Is not calling it at all or is ok now?

Comment: Please post the angular code, in your question (edit it)